# Why doesn't my tripod ball head fit properly on the legs any more?

Tags: troubleshooting, tripod, tripod-heads, tripod-socket, ball-head

I've a tripod ball head (Manfroto 496RC2) which used to fit perfectly with a tripod legs (Trax travelpod 480A) that I had. I removed the head a couple of days back and now I'm trying to reattach them but it just will not fit.  It seems like either the screw in the legs have somehow become smaller or the attachment on the ball head have gotten wider.

Has anyone else had similar problem with their tripod legs / head?

Is their any kind of setting on the ball head that I'm unaware of?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just figured out why it happened.
It turns out the thread on the ball head got pushed inside (for whatever reason) and so, the screw on the legs could not fit properly.

Answer (score 0):

This may be completely off, but has the temperature changed drastically? Try putting it in a refrigerator or cold place and it should shrink a bit.